# How to remove ESlint error no-unresolved from importing 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

no-unresolved https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md

[image]

After installing `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`
[image]

My **.eslintrc** config

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/no-find-dom-node": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true
  },
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": "webpack"
  }
}
```

---

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "coinhover",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Leon Gaban",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "test": "eslint app && jest",
    "test:fix": "eslint --fix app"
  },
  "now": {
    "name": "coinhover",
    "engines": {
      "node": "7.4.x"
    },
    "alias": "coinhover.io"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {},
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.11.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "ramda": "^0.24.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "next",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

#### Webpack

```
import fs from 'fs'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import path from 'path'
import chalk from 'chalk'

const coinhover = path.resolve(__dirname, "coinhover")
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "public/src")
const log = console.log
// https://gist.github.com/leongaban/dc92204454b3513e511645af98107775

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/public/src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "coinhover.css",
  disable: false,
  allChunks: true
})

const CopyWebpackPluginConfig = new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "public/src/static", to: "static" }])

const PATHS = {
  app: src,
  build: coinhover,
}

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production'
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})

const base = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: coinhover
        })
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src')]
  }
}

const developmentConfig = {
  devServer: {
    publicPath: "",
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    // hot: false,
    quiet: true,
    inline: true,
    compress: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    productionPlugin
  ]
}

log(`${chalk.magenta(' ')} ${chalk.italic.green('npm run:')} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}`)

export default Object.assign({}, base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
)
```

Comment: Can you put your `package.json` `dependencies` as well? (As opposed to just your `devDependencies`)

Comment: @Swivel just added!

Comment: I just noticed you're using `webpack` as the resolver. What does your webpack config look like? Specifically, if you have any `resolve` config.

Comment: @Swivel added webpack! And yeah have a resolve config in there

Comment: This may be of use: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/352#issuecomment-284216693

Comment: what operating system do you use?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can add an option to [ignore case](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md#casesensitive):

```
"rules": {
   "import/no-unresolved": [
      2, 
      { "caseSensitive": false }
   ]
}
```

[This thread at github](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/720) also describes how the linter was checking case for parts of the path which come before the folder containing package.json. If you for example have the path:
`C:/Workspace/app` and you navigate to it using `cd C:/workspace/app` (lowercase workspace), the linter would also give an error on the imports. Looks like it should now be fixed, but perhaps you are still using an older version.

Comment: `caseSensitive` needs to have quotes: `"caseSensitive"`

Comment: What is the "2" first element on array for?

Comment: @JoseRojas

- 0 or "off": Turn the rule off, ESLint will not report any problems.
- 1 or "warn": Turn the rule on as a warning (the code will still run). ESLint will report the problems but not block the code execution.
- 2 or "error": Turn the rule on as an error (the code will not run). ESLint will report the problems and block the code execution.

Answer (score 13):

Try installing `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` and adding this to your **.eslintrc**:

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": "webpack"
}
```

Comment: Hmm just installed that and updated my config file above but still getting those highlights :( Oh error changed, adding screenshot above...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src'), 'node_modules', path.resolve('node_modules')],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it helped me

If you would like to enable this rule, then:

- Enable the rule within your config: 'import/no-unresolved': 'error'
- Install and configure the TypeScript import resolver: [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your webpack config is written in ES6 format, which doesn't play well with `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`.

So, you either refactor your `webpack.config.js` using ES5 syntax, or you get rid of `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`.

See here for the full solution:  [eslint plugin docs](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/352#issuecomment-284216693)

Comment: @LeonGaban I haven't suggested any solution instead just edited the post