# Webpack Externals - Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: webpack, eslint

According to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) I can reference an external CDN for a module and use it as normal. However, es-lint gives the following error: `Unable to resolve path to module 'jquery'`.

My config is copied directly from the docs:

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
},
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of the error without having to resort to this?

```
/* eslint import/no-unresolved: 0 */
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: just were surfing this issue and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208496) which did the job.