# ESLint and Babel Config

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, eslint

Currently, I am trying to use ESLint for my project, I am using the `Airbnb` style guide alongside ESLint, and I am also using Husky to run pre-commit checks. I have faced an issue as I cannot commit code due to ESLint reporting errors of `import/no-unresolved`. I am making use of path aliasing, so my import statements are something like this.

```
import foo from '@foo`
```

as opposed to

```
import foo from '../foo'
```

I have googled what I could do, I came across the option of using `eslint-plugin import`. But that didn't solve the issue. I don't know what else to do, here's a snippet of my ESLint file and Babel file respectively.

`eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'airbnb-base',
        'prettier',
    ],
    plugins: ['import', '@babel', 'prettier'],
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        sourceType: 'module',
        requireConfigFile: 'false',
        babelOptions: { configFile: './Backend/babel.config.js' },
    },
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            'babel-module': { allowExistingDirectories: true },
        },
    },
    rules: {
        'prettier/prettier': 'error',
        'arrow-body-style': 'off',
        'no-console': ['error', { allow: ['warn', 'error', 'log'] }],
        'prefer-const': ['error'],
        'no-var': ['error'],
        'no-new-object': ['error'],
        'object-shorthand': ['error'],
        'quote-props': ['error', 'as-needed'],
        'prefer-object-spread': ['error'],
        'array-callback-return': ['error'],
        'prefer-destructuring': [
            'error',
            {
                array: true,
                object: true,
            },
            {
                enforceForRenamedProperties: false,
            },
        ],
        quotes: [2, 'single', { allowTemplateLiterals: true }],
        'prefer-template': ['error'],
        'no-useless-escape': ['error'],
        'prefer-rest-params': ['error'],
        'no-new-func': ['error'],
        'no-param-reassign': ['error'],
        'prefer-spread': ['error'],
        'function-paren-newline': ['error'],
        'prefer-arrow-callback': ['error'],
        'implicit-arrow-linebreak': ['error'],
        'no-useless-constructor': ['error'],
        semi: ['error', 'never'],
        'eol-last': 0,
        'no-multiple-empty-lines': ['error', { max: 1, maxEOF: 0 }],
    },
}
```

`babel.config.js`

```
const TARGETS_NODE = '12.13.0'
const CORE_JS_VERSION = '3.6'

module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: { node: TARGETS_NODE },
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: {
                    version: CORE_JS_VERSION,
                    proposals: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
    plugins: [
        [
            'babel-plugin-module-resolver',
            {
                alias: {
                    '@modules': './src/modules',
                    '@utils': './src/utils',
                    '@shared': './src/shared',
                    '@config': './src/config',
                    '@validations': './src/validations',
                    '@controllers': './src/controllers',
                    '@models': './src/models',
                    '@routes': './src/routes',
                },
            },
        ],
        [('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true })],
        [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
                corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
                version: '^7.8.3',
            },
        ],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }],
    ],
}
```

I use `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to resolve paths while transpiling.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option to [ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208367/how-to-remove-eslint-error-no-unresolved-from-importing-react#:%7E:text=an%20option%20to-,ignore%20case,-%3A):

```
"rules": {
   "import/no-unresolved": [
      2, 
      { "caseSensitive": false }
   ]
}
```

This thread at [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208367/how-to-remove-eslint-error-no-unresolved-from-importing-react#:%7E:text=This%20thread%20at%20github) also describes how the linter was checking case for parts of the path which come before the folder containing package.json. If you for example have the path: C:/Workspace/app and you navigate to it using cd C:/workspace/app (lowercase workspace), the linter would also give an error on the imports. Looks like it should now be fixed, but perhaps you are still using an older version.